# How to model if-expressions with actor systems?

Tags: scala, parallel-processing, functional-programming, akka, actor

I'm [trying to emulate](https://github.com/curiosag/picoservice) a simple functional language using an actor based execution model where issues arose modelling if-expression.

Actor systems nowadays are used basically for [speeding up all kind of stuff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493001/good-use-case-for-akka?rq=1#comment4919406_4494512) by avoiding OS locks and stalled threads or to [make microservices less painful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-actors-introduction), but initially it was supposed to be an alternative model of computation in general [[1]](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Hewitt-Meijer-and-Szyperski-The-Actor-Model-everything-you-wanted-to-know-but-were-afraid-to-ask)[[2]](http://worrydream.com/refs/Hewitt-ActorModel.pdf), a contemporary take on it may be [propagation networks](https://www.cs.tufts.edu/%7Enr/cs257/archive/alexey-radul/phd-thesis.pdf). So this should be capable to cover any programming language construct and certainly an `if`, right?

While I'm aware that this is occasionally met with irritation, I saw [one timid attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106477/how-can-i-get-fibonaccin-in-an-efficient-way-with-scala-actor) to move towards recursive algorithms represented using akka actors (I've refurbished it and added [further examples](https://github.com/curiosag/akka-examples) including the one given below). That attempt halted at function calls, but why not go further and also model operators and if conditions with actors? In fact the smalltalk language applies this model and yields a precursor of the actor concept, as has been pointed out in the accepted answers below.

Surprisingly recursive function calls aren't much of an issue, but `if`<sup>1</sup> is, due to it's potentially stateful nature.

Given the clause `C: if a then x else y`, here's the problem:

My initial idea was, that `C` is an actor behaving like a function with 3 parameters `(a,x,y)` that returns either `x` or `y` depending on `a`. Being maximally parallel [[2]](http://worrydream.com/refs/Hewitt-ActorModel.pdf) `a,x` and `y` would be evaluated simultaneously and passed as messages to `C`. Now, this isn't really good, if `C` is the exit condition of a recursive function `f`, sending one branch of `f` in an infinite recursion. Also if `x` or `y` have side effects one can't just evaluate both of them. Let's take this recursive sum (which is *not the usual factorial*, stupid as such and  could be made tail recursive, but that's not the point)

```
f(n) =  if n <= 0
      0
    else
      n + f(n -1)
```

Note, that I'd like to create an if-expression resembling the one of Scala, see the ([spec](https://www.scala-lang.org/old/sites/default/files/linuxsoft_archives/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), p. 88), or Haskell, for that matter, rather than an if-statement that relies on side-effects.

`f(0)` would cause 3 concurrent evaluations

- `n <= 0` (ok)
- `0` (ok)
- `n + f(n -1)` (bad, introducing the weird behavior that the call to f(n) actually will return (yielding 0) but the evaluation of its branches continues infinitely)

I can see these options from here:

- The whole computation becomes stateful and the evaluation of either `x`
  or `y` only happens after `a` has been calculated (mandatory if x or y have side effects).
- Some guarding mechanism gets introduced that renders `x` or `y` not
  applicable for arguments outside a certain range upon the call of `f`. They might evaluate to some "not applicable" marker instead of a value, which will not be used in `C` anyway, since it comes from a branch which isn't relevant.

I'm not sure at this point, If I didn't miss out on the question at a fundamental level and there are obvious other approaches that I just don't see. Input appreciated :)

Btw. see [this](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Conditional_structures) for an exhaustive list of conditional branching in different languages, without giving their semantics, and, not exhaustive, the [wiki page on conditionals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_(computer_programming)), with semantics, and [this](http://igoro.com/archive/fast-and-slow-if-statements-branch-prediction-in-modern-processors/) for a discussion how the question at hand is an issue till down to the level of hardware.

<sup>1</sup> I'm aware that an `if` could be seen as a special case of pattern matching, but then the question is, how to model the different cases of a match expression using actors. But maybe that wasn't even intended in the first place, matching is just something that every actor can do without referring to other specialized "match-actors". On the other hand it has been stated that "everything is an actor", rather confusing[[2]](http://worrydream.com/refs/Hewitt-ActorModel.pdf). Btw. does anybody have a clear notion what the `[#message whatever]` notation is meant to be in that paper? `#` is irritatingly undefined. Maybe smalltak gives a hint, there it indicates [a symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smalltalk).

Comment: Your implementation of factorial is stateful because the recursive call is not positioned at the tail (because once `f(n-1)` returns, you still have to add something). I figure this is a fundamental problem here as well as it is in FP or imperative implementations. the technique for making accumulating recursive funcitons TCO-aware might help. (having the accumulator as an extra parameter)

Comment: I'm aware that this could be made tail recursive, it is not about the recursion or the sum, it is about the implementation of the "if". And it isn't even factorial, it's a stupid sum ;)

Comment: Can you make a parallel with Prolog's `occurs_check` problem here? I think that parallel computations of if branches are a problem *per se*, especially if you want your `if` to be a guard condition in a recursive function. The aim of executing both branches concurrently and to choose the result in the end is to finish earlier by actually doing more work. But the aim of a recursion guard is to actually prevent the code from searching for things that don't exist. (which your second branch actually does)

Comment: Laurent, I'm aware that I could just NOT do the parallel computation (that's one option), and it may serve no pragmatic goal, but part of the question is, what to do in the face of it, further encouraged by the initial proposal for actor systems by Hewitt e.a. Thx for the occurs_check hint, though. And for voting for the guard approach, implicitly, or didn't you?

Comment: Fair enough, I can't bring you anything further, I'm only vaguely aware of the actor model :) The crux of what I'm trying to say in my previous comments : there is a fundamental problem in the imperative `if` : it is used for two different things - actually branching, and guarding recusion. But imperative programming gets away with it by having in its semantics that it executes not both of the branches (the side-effects of the unmatched branch shall not appear in the post-state) I'd vote for the stateful solution in the case of f appearing in one of the branches, the second one in other cases.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Out of curiosity: Why are you calling a non tail recursive function stateful? There are still no variables. The state is solely hold in the call stack as with any tail recursive function (even though there is only a single call stack frame in the latter case).

Comment: @bob: out of abuse of language probably. Every additional stack frame you keep is some state necessarily kept to pursue leftover computations. The single stack frame still necessary for TCO is the link between the recursive function and the outside world. The computation is "stateless" (maybe "functional" would be more appropriale) in the TCO version in that the state of computation is only passed as an argument to the next recursive call.

Comment: @LaurentLARIZZA Ah I see, we use the term state slightly different. As to me state is the portion of the program that changes while the program is running. In this sense the call stack isn't stateful but only holds (constant) data. Strictly speaking TCO renders the call stack stateful again, since a single frame is reused..

Comment: Usually actors (in practice) are supposed to do significant operations, not emulate imperative programming constructs. But for the sake of the discussion, how would such an actor system look like? Off the top of my head I see 2 configurations: R (result) listens to 2 actors, called T and E (then and else). Then, someone sends C (the condition) to both T and E and only one responds. You basically implemented: ``R <- lambda c -> if(c) { return T(); } if(!c) { return E(); }``. Or: you have 3 actors collaborating: I, T, E. You send C to I and I triggers either T or E depending on C.

Comment: @curiosa Glad you mentioned haskell. Haskell is a *lazy* language. As such, the question of both ``then`` and ``else`` being executed is a non-issue. And no one in their right mind would consider a "concurrent if then else" which executes everything always as correct or useful. I know there is some difference between those computer science people who see actor model as a theory and those who actually use actors as a design element for larger systems. I am a practical guy. We once did a navigation system (automotive) which had actors like: "Router", "Positioning";  We did not have "if" actors.

Comment: @curiosa Exactly! And how is a workflow not imperative by its very nature? British warship in the age of sails example workflow: "If flag == WHITE_FLAG then board() else shoot_em_to_smithereens();"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a little bit of a misconception in your question. In functional languages, `if` is not necessarily a function of three parameters. Rather, it is sometimes two functions of two parameters.

In particular, that is how the *Church Encoding of Booleans* works in λ-calculus: there are *two* functions, let's call them `True` and `False`. Both functions have two parameters. `True` simply returns the first argument, `False` simply returns the second argument.

First, let's define two functions called `true` and `false`. We could define them any way we want, they are completely arbitrary, but we will define them in a very special way which has some advantages as we will see later (I will use ECMAScript as a somewhat reasonable approximation of λ-calculus that is probably readable by a bigger portion of visitors to this site than λ-calculus itself):

```js
const tru = (thn, _  ) => thn,
      fls = (_  , els) => els;
```

`tru` is a function with two parameters which simply ignores its second argument and returns the first. `fls` is also a function with two parameters which simply ignores its first argument and returns the second.

Why did we encode `tru` and `fls` this way? Well, this way, the two functions not only represent the two concepts of `true` and `false`, no, at the same time, they also represent the concept of "choice", in other words, they are also an `if`/`then`/`else` expression! We evaluate the `if` condition and pass it the `then` block and the `else` block as arguments. If the condition evaluates to `tru`, it will return the `then` block, if it evaluates to `fls`, it will return the `else` block. Here's an example:

```js
tru(23, 42);
// => 23
```

This returns `23`, and this:

```js
fls(23, 42);
// => 42
```

returns `42`, just as you would expect.

There is a wrinkle, however:

```js
tru(console.log("then branch"), console.log("else branch"));
// then branch
// else branch
```

This prints *both* `then branch` and `else branch`! Why?

Well, it *returns* the return value of the first argument, but it *evaluates* both arguments, since ECMAScript is strict and always evaluates all arguments to a function before calling the function. IOW: it evaluates the first argument which is `console.log("then branch")`, which simply returns `undefined` and has the side-effect of printing `then branch` to the console, *and* it evaluates the second argument, which also returns `undefined` and prints to the console as a side-effect. Then, it returns the first `undefined`.

In λ-calculus, where this encoding was invented, that's not a problem: λ-calculus is *pure*, which means it doesn't have any side-effects; therefore you would never notice that the second argument also gets evaluated. Plus, λ-calculus is *lazy* (or at least, it is often evaluated under normal order), meaning, it doesn't actually evaluate arguments which aren't needed. So, IOW: in λ-calculus the second argument would never be evaluated, and if it were, we wouldn't notice.

ECMAScript, however, is *strict*, i.e. it always evaluates all arguments. Well, actually, not always: the `if`/`then`/`else`, for example, only evaluates the `then` branch if the condition is `true` and only evaluates the `else` branch if the condition is `false`. And we want to replicate this behavior with our `iff`. Thankfully, even though ECMAScript isn't lazy, it has a way to delay the evaluation of a piece of code, the same way almost every other language does: wrap it in a function, and if you never call that function, the code will never get executed.

So, we wrap both blocks in a function, and at the end call the function that is returned:

```js
tru(() => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"))();
// then branch
```

prints `then branch` and

```js
fls(() => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"))();
// else branch
```

prints `else branch`.

We could implement the traditional `if`/`then`/`else` this way:

```js
const iff = (cnd, thn, els) => cnd(thn, els);

iff(tru, 23, 42);
// => 23

iff(fls, 23, 42);
// => 42
```

Again, we need some extra function wrapping when calling the `iff` function and the extra function call parentheses in the definition of `iff`, for the same reason as above:

```js
const iff = (cnd, thn, els) => cnd(thn, els)();

iff(tru, () => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"));
// then branch

iff(fls, () => console.log("then branch"), () => console.log("else branch"));
// else branch
```

Now that we have those two definitions, we can implement `or`. First, we look at the truth table for `or`: if the first operand is truthy, then the result of the expression is the same as the first operand. Otherwise, the result of the expression is the result of the second operand. In short: if the first operand is `true`, we return the first operand, otherwise we return the second operand:

```js
const orr = (a, b) => iff(a, () => a, () => b);
```

Let's check out that it works:

```js
orr(tru,tru);
// => tru(thn, _) {}

orr(tru,fls);
// => tru(thn, _) {}

orr(fls,tru);
// => tru(thn, _) {}

orr(fls,fls);
// => fls(_, els) {}
```

Great! However, that definition looks a little ugly. Remember, `tru` and `fls` already act like a conditional all by themselves, so really there is no need for `iff`, and thus all of that function wrapping at all:

```js
const orr = (a, b) => a(a, b);
```

There you have it: `or` (plus other boolean operators) defined with nothing but function definitions and function calls in just a handful of lines:

```js
const tru = (thn, _  ) => thn,
      fls = (_  , els) => els,
      orr = (a  , b  ) => a(a, b),
      nnd = (a  , b  ) => a(b, a),
      ntt = a          => a(fls, tru),
      xor = (a  , b  ) => a(ntt(b), b),
      iff = (cnd, thn, els) => cnd(thn, els)();
```

Unfortunately, this implementation is rather useless: there are no functions or operators in ECMAScript which return `tru` or `fls`, they all return `true` or `false`, so we can't use them with our functions. But there's still a lot we can do. For example, this is an implementation of a singly-linked list:

```js
const cons = (hd, tl) => which => which(hd, tl),
      car  = l => l(tru),
      cdr  = l => l(fls);
```

You may have noticed something peculiar: `tru` and `fls` play a double role, they act both as the data values `true` and `false`, but at the same time, they also act as a conditional expression. They are *data* and *behavior*, bundled up into one … uhm … "thing" … or (dare I say) *object*! Does this idea of identifying data and behavior remind us of anything?

Indeed, `tru` and `fls` are *objects*. And, if you have ever used Smalltalk, Self, Newspeak or other pure object-oriented languages, you will have noticed that they implement booleans in exactly the same way: two objects `true` and `false` which have method named `if` that takes two blocks (functions, lambdas, whatever) as arguments and evaluates one of them.

Here's an example of what it might look like in Scala:

```scala
sealed abstract trait Buul {
  def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: ⇒ U)(els: ⇒ V): T
  def &&&(other: ⇒ Buul): Buul
  def |||(other: ⇒ Buul): Buul
  def ntt: Buul
}

case object Tru extends Buul {
  override def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: ⇒ U)(els: ⇒ V): U = thn
  override def &&&(other: ⇒ Buul) = other
  override def |||(other: ⇒ Buul): this.type = this
  override def ntt = Fls
}

case object Fls extends Buul {
  override def apply[T, U <: T, V <: T](thn: ⇒ U)(els: ⇒ V): V = els
  override def &&&(other: ⇒ Buul): this.type = this
  override def |||(other: ⇒ Buul) = other
  override def ntt = Tru
}

object BuulExtension {
  import scala.language.implicitConversions
  implicit def boolean2Buul(b: ⇒ Boolean) = if (b) Tru else Fls
}

import BuulExtension._

(2 < 3) { println("2 is less than 3") } { println("2 is greater than 3") }
// 2 is less than 3
```

Given the very close relationship between OO and actors (they are pretty much the same thing, actually), which is not historically surprising (Alan Kay based Smalltalk on Carl Hewitt's PLANNER; Carl Hewitt based Actors on Alan Kay's Smalltalk), I wouldn't be surprised if this turned out to be a step in the right direction to solve your problem.

Comment: I posted this as community wiki, since it only gives a *potential* direction for an answer, not a full answer and even not necessarily the right direction.

Comment: @curiosa: Smalltalk is mentioned explicitly in the paper you linked. I'm not sure I have any textual references for the other direction, but I remember Alan Kay explicitly referencing PLANNER in several interviews, in particular how the goal-directed execution model influenced the message-driven execution model of Smalltalk, which in turn was the inspiration for the message-driven execution model of Actors.

Comment: I considered writing the first part in Scala, but a) I already had it lying around in ECMAScript, and b) the type annotations would be distracting.

Comment: An objection to call an "***implementation***" ( 1st eval both, next yield one of them based on the (if-ed)-control-state ) **to reflect** the choice. This may be working in some kind of implementation, but it is not a choice as we know it. A choice to "***KILL THE BEAVER*** (to save the tree)" **OR "*KILL THE TREE***" will normally result in having either the TREE or the BEAVER kept alive. Not in the "**implementation**"-argued example above, where you will receive both a DEAD beaver AND a DEAD tree, with an ex-post advice, the code would prefer to KILL only one of 'em (a post-mortem advice)

Comment: Yes, but killing is a side effect, right? What about the functional interpretation, free of side effects?

Comment: @JörgWMittag Isn't `tru`/`fls` just pattern matching accomplished with bare functions?

Comment: @user3666197: You are reading much too intricate semantics into simple pseudo-code. As I wrote in the introductory paragraphs, I am simply using ECMAScript as a somewhat more familiar notation for &lambda;-calculus. The problem you describe does not exist in &lambda;-calculus, since that is pure. Also, I do address that problem a couple paragraphs further down, *and fix it*.

Comment: @bob: Isn't `if` just crippled pattern matching? ;-)

Comment: **No, it is rather an evidence** of an ill-formed assumption, that an if-decision evaluation does not have to take place "before" evaluation of the choice-made. If you forbid any change of a global state-space, you may defend either a "just"-[CONCURRENT] evaluation or a true-[PARALLEL] evaluation (which, if pedantic, will then come at a cost to have to wait for the slowest evaluation-path, before leaving such true-[PARALLEL] processing-section, which is not what one would expect or call it a benefit, would it? )

Comment: Note that there is another interesting connection between Actors and FP: Scheme was originally created as a vehicle for understanding Actors. The authors were already familiar with LISP, so they created a minimal LISP and then added Actors to it. Basically, in addition to `LAMBDA` for creating functions, you also had `ALPHA` for creating actors and in addition to `APPLY` for calling functions, you also had `SEND` for sending messages. The interpreter was originally written in assembly and treated actors and functions completely separately. When they realized that there was no need for `SEND` …

Comment: … and `APPLY` to be separate, it could just be one operation which checks the type of the argument whether it is a `LAMBDA` or an `ALPHA`. When they refactored the interpreter that way, they noticed something quite profound: both branches of the `IF` were the same! In a procedural languages with first-class procedures, lexical scoping, lexical closures, and proper tail calls, actors and lambdas are *operationally the same thing*, the difference is just whether the primitives in your library are actors or lambdas. This shows a quite deep connection between Scheme-like and actor languages.

Comment: @JörgWMittag But with `if` you'd need equality somewhere, whereas pattern matching is solely based on structure, right?

Answer (score -1):

> **Q** : *didn't ( I ) miss out on the question at a fundamental level?*

Yes, you happened to have missed a cardinal point: even the functional-languages, that may otherwise enjoy the forms of AND- and/or OR-based fine-grain sorts of parallelism, do not grow as wild as not to respect the strictly **`[SERIAL]`** nature of the **`if ( expression1 ) expression2 [ else expression3 ]`**

You have spend many efforts on argumentation about recursion-case(s) whereas the principal property was left out of your view. State-fullness is the Mother Nature of the computing ( these toys are nothing but finite state automata, no matter how large the state-space might be, it is and always will principally remain finite ).

Even the cited Scala p.88 confirms this: "The conditional expression is evaluated by evaluating first *e1*. If this evaluates to `true`, the result of evaluating *e2* is returned, otherwise the result of evaluating `e3` is returned." - which is a pure-`[SERIAL]` process-recipe ( one step after another ).

One may remember, that even the evaluation of **`expression1`** may have (and does have ) state-change effects ( not only "side-effects" ), but indeed state-change effects ( PRNG-steps into a new state whenever a random-number was asked to get generated and many similar situations )

Thus the `if e1 then e2 else e3` has to obey a pure-**`[SERIAL]`** implementation, no matter what benefits may be brought into action from fine-grain {AND|OR}-based-parallelism ( may see many working examples thereof in languages that can use 'em right since late 70-ies early 80-ies )

Comment: Thx for the effort, but dunno. You see, e.g. a parallel evaluation of if `a > b then a - b else b - a` isn't a problem at all IMO. I'd also appreciate an answer bringing light to it from the actor perspective. To clarify: I didn't want to mimmick the execution model of Scala, it's about having an expression instead of a statement. "many working examples thereof ...": of serial implementations? Of course, but If you could name a parallel one I'd be glad. Could you also corroborate your claim of "has to obey a pure-serial implementation..." with further work or references? Doesn't seem obvious.